# Convert series contains string of list to a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, series

I'd to calculate the sum of a series which seems contain a string list but I got many ValueError and can't convert it to a simple series.

Here my code

```
with open("./devicescores.csv", 'r') as file:
  csvreader = pd.read_csv(file)
  for row in csvreader:
    csvreader.to_excel (r'File name.xlsx', sheet_name="Testing",index = False, header=True)
  df = pd.read_excel('File name.xlsx', dtype={'scoreTable':str})
  df['score1'] = df['scoreTable'].str.split('{', expand=True)[1]
  df['score1'] = df['score1'].str.split('scores', expand=True)[1]
  df['score1'] = df['score1'].str.split('":', expand=True)[1]
  df['score1'] = df['score1'].str.split(',"_id', expand=True)[0]

  df['score3'] = df['scoreTable'].str.split('{', expand=True)[3]
  df['score3'] = df['score3'].str.split('scores', expand=True)[1]
  df['score3'] = df['score3'].str.split('":', expand=True)[1]
  df['score3'] = df['score3'].str.split(',"_id', expand=True)[0]
  
  df['score5'] = df['scoreTable'].str.split('{', expand=True)[5]
  df['score5'] = df['score5'].str.split('scores', expand=True)[1]
  df['score5'] = df['score5'].str.split('":', expand=True)[1]
  df['score5'] = df['score5'].str.split(',"_id', expand=True)[0]
  df = df.drop('scoreTable', axis=1)

  df.rename(columns = {'score1':'scorePlayer1'}, inplace = True)
  df.rename(columns = {'score3':'scorePlayer2'}, inplace = True)
  df.rename(columns = {'score5':'scorePlayer3'}, inplace = True)
  
  df = df[['house', 'unit', 'deviceName', 'scorePlayer1', 'scorePlayer2','scorePlayer3']]
```

When `devicescores.csv` is a `csv` file exported from MongoDB

My goal is to get the sum of df.scorePlayer1, output : 20

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. I don't understand what you're asking. It seems like `df` is the most important aspect of this question, but it's not defined here, and `s` seems to be irrelevant to the problem. What output do you want anyway? 20? Or a series containing 20? Or NaN since a series of lists doesn't have a sum per se? Please make a [mre] including data, expected output, and complete but minimal code. If the error messages would help, please provide them [in full](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). You can [edit].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: DId you maybe export a `json` file instead of a `csv` file? If so, better convert the file first, makes it easier, or use `pandas` to read a `json` file.

Comment: @Gijs I never deal with `json` file, it's why I choose to export to `csv` file.

Comment: It looks like there's a lot of `{` and `}` in your file. You may have not specified `type` with `mongoexport`? Read here https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoexport/.

Comment: @Gijs I export the data using MongoDB Compass and I have no option to specify any type except the format of the file (`csv` or `json`)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a Series of lists.

If you want the sum per row, use:

```
df.scorePlayer1.apply(sum)
```

Output:

```
0    20
Name: scorePlayer1, dtype: int64
```

From the total sum:

```
import numpy as np
np.array(df['scorePlayer1'].tolist()).sum()

# alternative
df['scorePlayer1'].explode().sum()
```

Output: `20`

Comment: With ```df.scorePlayer1.apply(sum)```
I got ```TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'```

Comment: With ```np.array(df['scorePlayer1'].tolist()).sum()```
I got :
 ```return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial, where)
numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncNoLoopError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U15'), dtype('<U15')) -> None```

and with ```df.scorePlayer1.apply(sum)```
I got ```[0,10,0,0,0,10]```

Comment: @HanarDept this mean you also have strings on your data. What is the output of `df['scorePlayer1'].to_list()`? (If too large, of `df['scorePlayer1'].head().to_list()`)

Comment: `df['scorePlayer1'].to_list()`  and `df['scorePlayer1'].head().to_list())` gave me : ```['[0,10,0,0,0,10]']```

Comment: It seems we have a series element contains a string which is string, isn't ? Or I miss something ?

Comment: Can you try `from ast import literal_eval ; df['scorePlayer1'] = df['scorePlayer1'].apply(literal_eval)`

Comment: `from ast import literal_eval 

df['scorePlayer1'] = df['scorePlayer1'].apply(literal_eval)
for i in df['scorePlayer1']:
  print(sum(i))`

I got `20` but I still didn't get, why `sum(df['scorePlayer1']` return `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'` ?

Comment: Because of the default `start=0` parameter of [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum). But anyway, you shouldn't use python's `sum` with `pandas`.